# Custom sorting pipe for Angular 6

Tags: angular, sorting, angular2-custom-pipes

I am trying to sort my data in the ngFor loop , but my custom pipe doesnot work as intened , can anybody help me out...

```
  export class OrderbyLastMessagePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(array: Array<string>, args?: any): Array<string> {

    if (array !== undefined && array !== null && args !== '') {

      console.log('args', array);

        const direction = args === 'desc' ? 1 : -1;
        array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {

          console.log('args', a);

          if (a['lastUpdatedat'] < b['lastUpdatedat']) {
                return -1 * direction;
            } else if (a['lastUpdatedat'] > b['lastUpdatedat']) {
                return 1 * direction;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        });
    }
    return array;
}
```

My Component ng container is this , i am using two filters one for search and another for sort on specific lastupdatedat value which is the timestamp ...

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let User of uLists | orderbyLastMessage:'uLists':true">
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: @JBNizet that doesnot help ... can please point out what am i doing wrong ...

Comment: Please provide some example data for uLists.  Quick note: if uLIsts is a list of objects with lastUpdatedat properties, your pipe probably shouldn't accept a array of string.

Comment: The obvious wrong thing is that you're modifying the array, instead of returning a sortted copy. But as the article explains, you shouldn't have a filter pipe, and you shouldn't have a sort pipe. If you want more help, you need to clearly define "doesn't work".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very similar answered here

[Angular Custom Order Pipe sorting array correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53383949/angular-custom-order-pipe-sorting-array-correctly/53384111#53384111)

The user search must be done with input type text, keyup event, and array.filter method.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Two recommendations:

1. If you used angular CLI to generate your pipe, it's `name` is `orderByLastMessagePipe`.  You can see this in your code like such:

   `@Pipe({name: 'orderByLastMessagePipe'})`
2. The parameters you are passing to your pipe will always cause it to sort ascending.  With angular pipes, multiple parameters are delimited by `:`.  The `orderbyLastMessage:'uLists':true"` should be `orderbyLastMessage:'desc'` to sort descending, and `orderbyLastMessage` to sort ascending, or `orderbyLastMessage:'asc'`.

Change your template to:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let User of uLists | searchUser:filterUser | orderbyLastMessagePipe:'desc'">
```

See if that fixes your sorting.

**Edit**

The array parameter to your pipe is obviously not an `Array<string>`.  If you have a specific type for the objects in your array, the parameter should be typed to that `Array<SomeObject>`.  If not, any will do `Array<any>`, or just `any`.

This answer is NOT the correct way to do sorting due to poor performance as pointed out in previous comments.  Just trying to answer the specific question that is asked.

Comment: Changing this orderbyLastMessagePipe:'desc' also doesnot sort